# Store user input in an array or object

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know whether it is easier to store all the data from a text input where the user has to enter their surname in an array or in an object. And how do I do so?.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to show that you've tried to figure this out on your own. fwiw, I would use an object, but I'll leave it to you to figure out "how". If you run into trouble, come back here, show us the code you've written and the different things you've tried, and we can help fill the gaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
var dataArray = []; 
function storeData() {
    var data = document.getElementById("yourInput").value;
    dataArray.push(data);
}
```

This method uses arrays - personally I find them more easier to use than objects.